# how to zoom in and zoom out the images in gallery

Tags: android

i want to zoom in zoom out the group of images in galleryview.i have done zoom single image using imageview,here i need to zoom gallery view og images.how to do,please help me

gallery.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

```
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
```

//here i need the zoom functionality

```
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: I post a link of sample code at [here][1], hopes it can help


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268806/android-gallery-with-pinch-zoom

Comment: Go to other questions now, and accept the top-most answer, to provide expected feedback to the SO community.

Answer (score 2):

I  have try this code, it's working great. no need to waste your time for implementing image zooming functionality. just get these project and understand how to implement the a image into the view.

Here it is: http://blog.sephiroth.it/2011/04/04/imageview-zoom-and-scroll/

Comment: hi this only used for zoom the single imageview.actually i add the number of images into gallery view,so  i need to zoom the gallery of images

Comment: i m trying to add a zoom into the gallery view. when i finish i will send u.

Comment: thanks raja.please can u give ur mail id

Comment: hi raja did finish that zoom functionality of gallery view.if u finished please help me